# Send encrypted data wcf - windows phone

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm using WCF service to communicate with DB. My WP7.5 application sends data through WCF to DB. I use basichttpbinding, because WP supports only this one. I would like to send data in encrypted form. I know, that https is used for these purposes.
Here is my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="baseBinding" >
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="TestWCF.WcfNotificationService.WcfNotificationService">
    <endpoint address="base" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="baseBinding"
      contract="TestWCF.WcfNotificationService.IWcfNotificationService" />
    <host>
      <timeouts openTimeout="00:05:00" />
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

I've googled and found that I have to set securityMode to transport, but it gives me an exception, when I try to update service reference in my WP application. Could you help me please, how to achieve this, that data will be encrypted?
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

This is the error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme for https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

I get this, when I update service reference in client.

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem with the configuration. BasicHttpBinding needs to be configured to support https. For example look here : http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2008/07/16/https-with-basichttpbinding-note-to-self/

As pointed out there, you need to change:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="baseBinding" >
      </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

to

```
<basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="baseBinding" >
          <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
           </security>
      </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

In addition, change

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

to

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but when my WP app tries to connect through WCF I get error: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via

Comment: what's the config/code on the WP side? Does your service work with normal .NET console app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your WCF service in IIS make sure you have https binding configured with an SSL certificate. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232.aspx) to see how to configure this. If you are self hosting the service make sure you add a base address like this:

```
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://[machineName]/Service.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
```

Comment: I've tried this: <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://MyComputerName/service" />
          </baseAddresses>
          <timeouts openTimeout="00:05:00" />
        </host> but It is not working. Same problem

Comment: are you hosting on IIS or selfhost? And if you are in self host the base address that you are passing should start with https://machinename/...

Comment: I'm using it on Visual Studio development server for now, but wcf will be hosted on IIS.

Comment: So I've tried SSL Certificate but it's not working. When I click Browse in IIS Manager, the page/wcf service is not loaded

Comment: SSL is now working. But problem is when my WP app try to connect through wcf service. I get following exception The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via